# Obfuscating names with the same length in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `users` table in the database with a `first_name` column and a `last_name` column, I want to obfuscate the names but keep them at the same original length and upper/lower case, so for example, 'Aiden' would be 'Xxxxx' and 'Pierce' would be 'Xxxxxx'

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`REPEAT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

```
select 
case when initcap(first_name)=first_name then initcap(repeat('x',length(first_name))) else repeat('x',length(first_name)) end,
case when initcap(last_name)=last_name then initcap(repeat('x',length(last_name))) else repeat('x',length(last_name)) end
from tablename
```